# Is there a way to merge values from different (but similar) objects in list in Kotlin?

Tags: kotlin

Ok, so I have a `list<SomeObject>`

```
class SomeObject(
  val number: Int,
  val otherNumber: Int,
  val list<OtherObject>
)
```

The objects in the list can have same `number` and `otherNumber` but different values in their `list<OtherObject>`

I want to merge every object in the list with the same `number` and `otherNumber`. So for example if I have a `list<SomeObject>` with 3 entries:

1 = `SomeObject(1, 1, list<OtherObject>`

2 = `SomeObject(1, 1, list<OtherObject>`

3 = `SomeObject(1, 2, list<OtherObject>`

I would want entry 1 and 2 to become one list entry with the values of both lists combined.

I can do this with a lot of looping and stuff, however the list is super long and I cannot seem to do it in an efficient manner.

Is there some kotlin function for this? Or do anyone have a good suggestion as to how I should approach it?

Comment: i _think_ we can remove the android tag here, if it's just kotlin more people might see it and give you a better answer

Comment: Maybe consider using a set hashed based on number and otherNumber?

Comment: I agree with @user2233706. Building a `Map<Pair<Int, Int>, List<OtherObject>>` or something similar makes a lot of sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe this would be a fitting solution for you. Instead of `List<OtherObject>` I used a `List<String>` but that should not make a difference.

You might want to consider wrapping your `List<SomeObject>` into a `Sequence` to build up a filter that is executed all at once instead of actually applying `groupBy` and so on to the `List`. Also refer https://kotlinlang.org/docs/sequences.html

For explaination please check the comments in the code.

```
fun main() {
    val objects = listOf(
            SomeObject(1, 1, listOf("a")),
            SomeObject(1, 1, listOf("b")),
            SomeObject(1, 2, listOf("c")))


    // group all objects by number and othernumber (both have to match)
    val grouping = objects.groupBy { Pair(it.number, it.otherNumber) }

    // consolidate a grouping onto a new object, so
    // [Pair(1,1), List(SomeObject(1,1,["a","b"]), SomeObject(1,1,["c","d"])) ]
    // [Pair(2,1), List(SomeObject(2,1,["e","f"]), SomeObject(2,1,["g","h"])) ]
    // becomes
    // List(SomeObject(1,1,["a","b", "c", "d"]), SomeObject(2,1,["e","f", "g", "h"]))
    val consolidated = grouping.values.map {
        objectsWithSameNumber ->
        SomeObject(objectsWithSameNumber[0].number,
                   objectsWithSameNumber[0].otherNumber,
                   objectsWithSameNumber.flatMap { it.list })
    }

    /*
    1 1: [a, b]
    1 2: [c]
     */
    for (result in consolidated) {
        println(result)
    }
}

class SomeObject(
        val number: Int,
        val otherNumber: Int,
        val list: List<String>
){
    override fun toString(): String {
        return "$number $otherNumber: $list"
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked excellent for the example scenario, however, for the real list I ran out of memory as I have done before. So I think I'll have to do something completely different. I'll accept this answer anyways though since it answered the example question.

Comment: @Skrettinga Well - my solution will create new objects for each `number` and `otherNumber` combination. Maybe you want to think about reusing one of the objects and discarding the other ones after consolidation.